# Does the HTML "Living Standard" later become the "Working Draft"?

Tags: html, specifications, w3c

I have been studying about WHATWG and W3C from the articles https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium.

From what I understood I think WHATWG is a part of W3C. The WHATWG suggest new standards and features for HTML to browser vendors via W3C. That is first WHATWG documents all the new specifications and calls this document the *Living Standard* and then hand over this document to the W3C which rename this as *Working Draft*. WD is then made public and suggestions are taken over it and then after studying seriously by W3C membors they decide whether all the specs suggested are appropriate or not and then publishes their own modified version as the *Candidate Recommendation*. The CR is sent to all browser vendors to check if they can implement the specs mentioned. After receiveing all browser vendors suggestions they revise the whole document and modify accordingly and publish the document as *Proposed Recommendation*. This PR is then given the final call, that is everything is looked once again for final verification and then finally after making any changes needed the document *W3C Recommendation* is published.

My questions are:

1. Is the "Living Standard" of WHATWG and "Working Draft" of W3C one and the same thing?
2. Do browser vendors adhere to the "Living Standard" or "W3C Recommendation"?

Comment: The relationship between WHATWG and W3C is pretty complicated. But they are independent organisations. In general, the Living Standard contains more *aspirational* elements, i.e. more stuff that browsers haven't yet implemented, but have some intention to do so in the future. Note that "some intention" does not mean that it will ever happen. Sometimes, those elements are found to be unimplementable or unmaintainable or undesirable for any number of reasons or just aren't interesting enough for the browser makers to be willing to prioritize it sufficiently to make it happen.

Comment: The FAQ you linked to contains questions about [WHATWG and the W3C HTML WG](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#WHATWG_and_the_W3C_HTML_WG). Didn’t you read this section? What gave you the impression that "WHATWG is a part of W3C"?

Comment: @unor [This paragraph](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#What.27s_the_patent_story_for_WHATWG_standards.3F) gave me that impression. I thought WHATWG is an independent branch of w3c where specific people only work on web standards.

Comment: @user31782: Ah, I see. Everyone can create a [W3C Community Group](https://www.w3.org/community/); it’s a platform/service offered by the W3C, but the users don’t have to be affiliated with the W3C.

Comment: @unor Does that mean people just volunteer for free? Doesn't WHATWG have a team of developers which work whole day on the html draft and get paid for that?

Answer (score 5):

> Is the "Living Standard" of WHATWG and "Working Draft" of W3C one and the same thing?

No. A WHATWG Living Standard is continuously maintained, much like software is continuously maintained.

A W3C Working Draft is a snapshot publication on the road to W3C Recommendation, which is supposedly the final output (even though you can never really finish).

> Do browser vendors adhere to the "Living Standard" or "W3C Recommendation"?

Whenever there is a choice between WHATWG and W3C for a document, browsers follow the WHATWG document as they're actively maintained and more accurate.

Comment: I have certain doubts. 1. Could you explain what is meaning _snapshot publication_ -- sorry I am not native English speaker. 2. Does W3C, on receiving the Living Standard, modifies Living standard and then call it working draft? 3. If WHATWG document(Living standard) is more accurate then what is W3C doing? After all those phases in W3C from which Living Standard pass to become W3C reccommendation, does it become less accurate?

Comment: 1. An alternative way of saying it is that a W3C Working Draft is an intermediate publication. Not the end goal. 2. The W3C does not receive a Living Standard. 3. I don't really understand what the W3C is doing. As I wrote at https://annevankesteren.nl/2016/01/film-at-11 they are making a mess of things.

Comment: _The W3C does not receive a Living Standard_. Really? Then do they have their own html specifications? I thought W3C use WHATWG specs and modifies that.

Comment: They copy it (badly, and against the wishes of the WHATWG).

Comment: So WHATWG and W3C are completely independent organizations, both working on defining HTML. W3C first copies WHATWG spec and then modifies it and call it W3C recommendation. If this is true then I think W3C is not doing any good. If they want to have their own html standard then why copy others'? Create your own!.. Not only that they should make their own browser too to prove their spec is better.

Comment: @user31782 "Living standards" are impractical for many organisations, having snapshotted and strictly versioned specifications (that the W3C produces) is better for those organisations and the ecosystem at-large (so content producers can say "our API confirms to W3C HTML 5.0" which sets a baseline for feature support by the authors of software that consume that content). A "living standard" better captures the current ecosystem (so is better for people on the cutting edge) but is impractical for software that needs wide support for a long time (think "LTSB" software).

Answer (score 1):

### W3C:

1. Working Draft.
2. Working Draft. Last Call.
3. Candidate Recommendation.
4. Proposed Recommendation.
5. Recommendation. (WHATWG Living Standart analogue)